# Error when getting angular-translate JSON files in angular app

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-translate

I have an angular app with some i18n JSON files. The files work fine- the language of the site is changed perfectly depending on which one is selected. However, I get a funny console error which I can't figure out-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at en.json: 2

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream
```

The same error appears in the console for each file.

Is there something wrong with the way my file is structured?

example of data in en.json:

```
{ 
    "WELCOME" : "Welcome",
    "HOME" : "Home",
    "GO" : "Go",
    "LOGOUT" : "Log Out"
}
```

Comment: Did you check the real JSON using a service like http://jsonlint.com/?

Comment: I sure did- it says that it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your JSON file but, according to the console log, it seems your web server does not set correct response header `Content-Type` which should be `application/json`.
So your browser tries to interpret your file as a JavaScript file and find an invalid token.

For instance with Nginx, you could use mime type configuration file provided by HTML5-Boilerplate project (https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types) and include it into your Nginx configuration:

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

It contains the following directive setting `application/json` as content type for JSON:

```
types {
  application/json                      json;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how I can set the correct response header?

Comment: @bookthief Which webserver do you use?

Comment: How do you serve your angular app (how do you launch it) or where is it hosted?

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example of mime type configuration with Nginx.